# When needed to pull out an answer out of the list, reports it's nonexistent in the list

Tags: python, list

I wrote this Python 3.10 (PyPy) code, but it doesn't work:

```
keyboard = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'q']
letter1 = str(input())
x = 0
y = 25
a = keyboard.index(letter1, x, y)
a = a + 1 
print(keyboard[a])
```

The error being:

```
m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    a = keyboard.index(letter1, x, y)
ValueError: 'm' is not in list
```

So, the task is: you enter a letter of the alphabet from the keyboard, and it should give the next letter on the keyboard, e.g. if the input is "p" it will output "a". Though it outputs an error if input the letter M. Also, the automatic checker says it failed on the 5th out of 20 test, but doesn't say what is the mistake. Can I get some help? I'm just starting out, so sorry if I didn't mention something crucial. Thanks in advance!

I tried to enter the letter M to the input thingy, but it didn't work at and got me an error instead
I tried adding the letter Q after the letter M in the list, but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you aware that `.index(letter1, 0, 25)` searches elements 0 through 24 inclusive?

Comment: Just use `a = keyboard.index(letter1)`

Comment: Why did you specify `y=25`? `m` is after that.

Comment: Tangentially, `input` returns a string by definition, so `str(input())` is not useful (or, conversely, if you think it is, `str(str(str(input()))` will be three times as useful!)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> help(str.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    S.index(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Raises ValueError when the substring is not found.
```

in str.index method, start is inclusive while end is exclusive. that mean mathematicaly `[start, end)`

so in this case, you mentioned end to be 25. so this function will search in all indexes from 0 to 24, and wont search in for 25 index

so inorder to solve this, add +1 to the end index, so that it make index 25 ie end inclusive

ie

```
a = keyboard.index(letter1, x, y+1) # add +1 in end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keyboard = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm']
letter1 = str(input())
x = 0
y = 26
a = keyboard.index(letter1, x, y)
if a==25:
  print(keyboard[0])
else:
  print(keyboard[a+1])
```

`list.index(str,start,end)` will search for "str" starting from "start" to "end" but not including "end". So I have set `y=26` so that it will search from index 0 to 25.